# Combinatorics - Skat game question.

Tags: combinatorics

The following is a standard skat game deck.
It has a total of $32$ cards, where $8$ cards each belong to one of the $4$ colors.
There are $4$ aces, kings, queens and jacks. (from left to right in the image below)

Usually, the game is played with $3$ players, where each player gets $10$ cards randomly and the remaining $2$ cards are put in the middle. (to the *skat*)

[image: Skat deck]
*(Credits: Wikipedia)*

I want to know the probability that for exactly $2$ out of the $3$ players each one gets exactly one king and the remaining $2$ kings are put in the middle.

**My attempt:**
This seems to be a typical $k$-combinations problem using the hypergeometric distribution. Let's decompose the statement:

1. Choose $2$ kings to be in the *skat* (middle): $4 \choose 2$
2. Then, first choose $2$ players, elected to get one of the kings: $3 \choose 2$
3. For the first of those $2$ players, there are ${2 \choose 1} = 2$ possibilities to obtain a king
4. For the second player, there is ${1 \choose 1} = 1$ possibility to obtain a king
5. All kings have been used up
6. Player $1$ now needs to get assigned $9$ more cards: ${28 \choose 9}$
7. Player $2$ now needs to get assigned $9$ more cards: ${19 \choose 9}$

It seems like we can multiply all these combinations together, as they could be seen as chained one after the other. However, how can I determine my sample space size $|S|$, i.e. what is the number of combinations I would need to divide through to get the desired probability?

Is it simply
$$
|S| = {32 \choose 10} \cdot {22 \choose 10} \cdot {12 \choose 10} \cdot {2 \choose 2}
$$

Please correct me if my line of thought is wrong. Maybe there's some symmetry that may make this problem much easier, or this is simply the wrong approach. I'm pretty rusty with combinatorics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of having $2$ kings in the skat is:
$$\frac{4}{32}\times\frac{3}{31}=\frac{3}{248}$$

Given two kings in the skat, the probability of Player One having both remaining kings is:
$$\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{30}{2}}=\frac{45}{435}$$

The same for Player Two and Player Three. Since these are mutually exclusive, the probability that *some player* has both of the remaining kings is:
$$3*\frac{45}{435}=\frac{135}{435}$$

And the probability that *no player* has both kings (i.e. the probability you are looking for) is:
$$\frac{300}{435}=\frac{20}{29}$$

Thus, the overall probability of having two kings in the skat with no player having two kings is:
$$\frac{3}{248}\times\frac{20}{29}=\frac{15}{1798}$$

**Alternate approach:**

There are $\binom{32}{4}$ ways to choose the positions of the kings.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose two players to receive one king each, and  $10^2$ ways to choose the positions of the kings in those players' hands.

This gives us the final probability of:
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}\times10^2}{\binom{32}{4}}=\frac{300}{35960}=\frac{15}{1798}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take it that there are $4$ blue marbles (kings) and $28$ white marbles, and distribute in the manner specified using the hypergeometric distribution.

Choose two of the three players who will get $1$ king each with the scat getting $2$, and distribute in $\dfrac{\binom32\binom{10}1\binom{10}1\binom22}{\binom{32}4} = \frac{15}{1798}$

Comment: It is past 3 in the morning here, i am half asleep, shall review tomorrow for *sleepy errors*, if any.

Comment: *Sleepy errors* corrected, the traditional hypergeometric formula is simplest here.